# How to get Firestore collection snapshot via document id

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new in flutter and i need help with this
I'm trying to get data snapshot from  Firestore collection
but i need this snapshot result via document ID
this the  collection and document ID

[image]

this is the form

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
     stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('types').snapshots(),
     builder: (context, snapshot2) {
         if (snapshot2.hasData) {
           print(snapshot2.data?.docs);
           return DropdownButtonFormField(
             value: shopId,
             isDense: true,
             onChanged: (val) => setState(() => shopId = val as String?),
             items: snapshot2.data?.docs.map((
                 DocumentSnapshot document) {
               return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(

                 child:Text(document.get('type')),
                 value: document.get('type'),
               );
             }).toList(),

           );
         }
         else
           return Text('error');

     }
     ),
```

it's work but it's get all the data with Different document ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is as @HasanToufiqAhamed said to request only a single document in the stream:

```
 stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('types').doc("your document id").snapshots(),
```

Then in your builder, the `snapshot2.data` becomes a `DocumentSnapshot` instead of a `QuerySnapshot`, so you'll have to update the code for that:

```
builder: (context, snapshot2) {
  if (snapshot2.hasData) {
    var document = snapshot2.data!;
    return DropdownButtonFormField(
      value: shopId,
      isDense: true,
      onChanged: (val) => setState(() => shopId = val as String?),
      items: List.filled(1, new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        child:Text(document.get('type')),
        value: document.get('type'),
      ).toList(),
    );
  }
  else
    return Text('error');
  }
),
```

Answer (score 1):

`StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>` to `StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>`

And change stream query like this

`stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Product').doc('This is The document Id').snapshots(),`

Comment: after do your change i got an error withsnapshot2.data.docs